# In a finite field $F$, for $k$ a positive integer and $x,y \in F$, does $kx = ky$ imply $x = y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

I’m in the middle of a proof where I want to conclude that $x = y$ if: $$x + \dots + x = y + \dots + y,$$
(with each side having $k$ terms). I’m not sure if that follows though.

Also, if it does, do we have the same thing in an integral domain and a division ring?

Comment: Take $\Bbb F_2$ and $x+x=y+y$. This means $2x=2y$, with $2=0$. So it just means $0=0$.

Answer (score 5):

No. In $F=\mathbb{F}_4$ you have $2x=2y$ for all $x,y\in F.$ It holds if $k$ is coprime to the characteristic, which is equivalent to being invertible in the field.

Answer (score 4):

In $\mathbb{Z}_2$
$$
1 + 1 = 0 + 0 .
$$

Answer (score 2):

No for $k$ a multiple of the characteristic of $F$, yes otherwise.

If $k$ is a multiple of the characteristic of $F$, then $kx=0$ for all $x \in F$, so the map $x \mapsto kx$ is not injective.

If $k$ is not a multiple of the characteristic of $F$, then the sum of $k$ $1$s in $F$ is nonzero, and hence invertible since $F$ is a field. So, the map $x \mapsto (k1)x=kx$ would then be a bijection, and in particular, an injection.